# $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Dedekind domain

Tags: number-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, and that every PID is a Dedekind. But I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Dedekind, without using PID.

One strategy coul be to show that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\mathfrak{P}}$ is a field for every nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$. Could someone suggest me how to prove this?
Furthermore, what else am I supposed to prove to ensure that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Dedekind?

Comment: Do you know the prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Which of the many equivalent definitions / characterizations of Dedekind domains are you allowed to use?

Comment: @lhf i'm actually asked to describe prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and i know what are prime elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. But unfortunately (for some strange reason) i can't use PID property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides proving that every nonzero prime ideal is maximal, you need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is Noetherian and integrally closed.

To prove that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\mathfrak{P}}$ is a field for every nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$, prove that it is *finite*, because every finite domain is a field. See the spoiler below.

> To prove that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\mathfrak{P}}$ is finite, consider $I=\mathfrak{P} \cap \mathbb{Z}$. Then $I$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and so $I=p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$. This implies that $\mathfrak{P}$ contains $p\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and so $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\mathfrak{P}} \subseteq \frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{p\mathbb{Z}[i]}$ has at most $p^2$ elements.

Comment: i can't understand why $\mathbb{Z}[i]/p\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has $p^2$ elements

Comment: @hlf ohhh got it, $p$ for real part times $p$ for imaginary